# How to create TextView with reflection on android?

Tags: android, reflection

I'm trying to create a textview with reflection on android but I could not success and got an exception which I shown below. Can anyone share an example with me?

the thing what I am trying to do is very simple, I will create a textview and put some text into it with calling it's setText method.

```
TextView x = new TextView(this);
x.setText("asjdhjasd");
```

the codes

```
Class cls = Class.forName("android.widget.TextView"); 
Class param[] = new Class[1];
param[0] = context.getClass();

Constructor ct = cls.getConstructor(param); //THROWS AN EXCEPTION HERE CALLED NO SUCH METHOD EXCEPTION.

Object paramVal[] = new Object[1];
paramVal[0] = context;
Object retobj = ct.newInstance(paramVal);
```

**I solved the problem with doing this**

```
param[0] = Context.class; //instead of param[0] = context.getClass();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Constructor ct = cls.getConstructor( context.getClass() );
```

**EDIT:** Sorry I should have explained why.

When you see a method like this

```
getConstructor(Class... parameterTypes)
```

It isn't asking for an array of classes, it wants the classes as parameters. It's called varargs and you can read about it at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: bro I just solved before your comment :) thanks again. and here what I did """ param[0] = Context.class; """

Comment: Oh true, well that's interesting. You must have been calling getClass on a Context sub-class like Activity or something.

Comment: FYI, you might find it easier to read if you utilize the varargs technique I mentioned in the answer. Basically you could replace lines 2, 3 and 5 with "Constructor ct = cls.getConstructor( Context.class );"

Comment: I see bro, it's obvious that your way is easier than mine. thank you again.